# Populating a PartialView's model with content from the Parent page's model in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model

I am trying to figure out how to populate the Model of my Partial View. For example the PartialView model includes everything the user enters in a notes dialog such as Subject and NoteContent, but it additionally needs the Unique Id of the Model from the parent page which is a Product Id. This way when the note is saved from the dialog window I can save it for that specific product.

In the below example if the user is on the ParentPage viewing a Product with Id 12 and wants to add a note they would click the Notes button to open the dialog window, fill out a subject and content and hit submit. During this submission to the controller EntityModule should = "Product" and EntityKey should = 12 if the ProductId is 12. I am trying to figure out how the NoteViewModel will retrieve these two fields from the parent ViewModel.

**ProductViewModel.cshtml**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

**NoteViewModel.cshtml**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string EntityModule { get; set; }
public int EntityKey { get; set; }
public string Subject { get; set; }
public string Content { get; set; }
```

**ParentPage.cshtml**

```
@model MyApp.Web.ViewModels.Shared.ProductViewModel
@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_NotesPartial"); }
```

**_NotesPartial.cshtml**

```
@model MyApp.Web.ViewModels.Shared.NoteViewModel
<button id="open" class="btn btn-primary">Notes</button>

@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("window")
    .Title("About Alvar Aalto")
    .Visible(false)
    .Draggable()
    .Resizable()
    .Width(600)
    .Actions(actions => actions.Pin().Minimize().Maximize().Close())
    .Content(@<text>
    <form asp-action="_NotesPartial">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>NoteViewModel</h4>
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Subject" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input asp-for="Subject" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Subject" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Content" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <textarea asp-for="Content" class="form-control" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea><span asp-validation-for="Content" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </text>)
)

<script>
    $("#open").click(function () {
        var win = $("#window").data("kendoWindow");
        win.center();
        win.open();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways is to fill and pass the model through the parent page. For example:

```
public class ProductViewModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public NoteViewModel Note { get; set;}
}
```

Then, use something like this:

```
@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_NotesPartial", Model.Note); }
```

There is no RenderAction in MVC6, which was a good solution for such purposes:

```
Html.RenderAction("_NotesPartial", new { id = ProductViewModel.Id })
```

but still you can use it in MVC5.

Comment: I am currently using MVC 6 so I can simply just add a param to RenderPartialAsync and fulfull the NoteViewModel?

Comment: @BlakeRivell Yes, you can use this extension: `static Task RenderPartialAsync(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string partialViewName, object model)` and pass the model as a parameter. The `NoteViewModel` model should be prepared in the `ProductsController`, I guess.

Comment: @BlakeRivell You can also go the ugly way: `@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_NotesPartial", new NoteViewModel { Id = Model.Id } ); }`